# Link Django models together via GenericKey?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

i have the following models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField("User")
    
class User(AbstractUser):
     ...
    
class Subscription(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey("Team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64) # packageA, packageB
    max_activation_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    
class Activation(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey("Subscription", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package = models.ForeignKey("Package", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DatetimeField()
    
class PackageA(models.Model):
    ... 
    
    
class PackageB(models.Model):
    ...
```

A team has one subscription and it can activate one or more package and the same package could be activated more than one time. (number of times specified with "max_ativation_number")

**Example:**

A team has a subscription called ***Suite*** and the available packages are: ***EmailAccount*** and ***Calendar***
The team choose to activate 3 EmailAccount and 2 Calendar (packages are not tied to each other)

For that reason the team could activate the same package more times.

For every activation i need to create a new instance on **PackageA** or **PackageB** (it depends on the choice a team made) and then i should "link" to that instance somehow.

Should i use ***GenericKey*** field inside Activation model? I not only need the name of the chosen package but I also need to figure out which instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are trying to make a Many-To-Many relationship actually https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships:

[image]

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField("User")
    
class User(AbstractUser):
     ...
    
class Subscription(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey("Team", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    packages = models.ManyToManyField(Package, through=Activation)
    
class Package(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64) # packageA, packageB
    
class Activation(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey("Subscription", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package = models.ForeignKey("Package", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    max_activation_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    created = models.DatetimeField()
```

So in order to create Subscription `Suite` with  3 EmailAccount and 2 Calendar

```py
suite_subscription = Subscription.objects.create(name='Suite', team=team_1)
email_package = Package.objects.create(name='EmailAccount')
calendar_package = Package.objects.create(name='Calendar')
suite_subscription.activation_set.create(package=email_package, max_activation_number=3)
suite_subscription.activation_set.create(package=calendar_package, max_activation_number=2)
```

Now you have `suite_subscription` with 3 max email packages and 2 max calendar packages. Similarly to this, you can create extra packages and subscriptions...

And you can add as many custom attributes as you want to that "pivot" Activation table.

Comment: Hello! It is a bit different, following your example i need to create 3 different email_package instances (not just adding max_activation_number=3). But ok with manytomany i can create as many instances i need but the problem here is that it is NOT just a name "package_A" Or "package_B" those are real models so i have to link to them, i can not just have Package instance. Every package has its own model because it has specific logic and need to handle specific fields. For example for EmailPackage i need (account, password, smtp, imap etc) those fields are not needed for CalendarPackage

Comment: @Dail you can create extra models for those logic and link nullable OneToOne to the Package model (ex: EmailConfig, CalendarConfig...) and determine the type of package based on a not null reference. Or as you said, you can convert the package reference on Activation to GenericForeignKey. Both of them have different pros and cons so do your research and choose what fit your requirements best.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in multiple ways as you want to create a new package instance one solution is using [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#:%7E:text=Django%20includes%20a%20%E2%80%9Csignal%20dispatcher,some%20action%20has%20taken%20place.) to create the new instance of packages by using **post_save** signal `from django.db.models.signals import post_save`.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender= Activation)
def post_activation_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created'):
        # create new package instance
        ....
```